# How to show my Connected App

Tags: canvas

We have connected a third party application into Salesforce by making it a Connected App. In the manage app section we have also set it to show on multiple tabs but we are not able to see the app. Is there some other configuration that needs to be done in order to show a connected App in Salesforce Lightning?
We are seeing the app in Salesforce Class though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto Setup-->App Manager-->App Name
2. In 'Lightning Experience App Manager' Section there is a column
   'Visible In Lightning Experience'.Check if it sets to true.
3. If it is Managed Package and it is unchecked then you need to
   contact to your 3rd party application and make it visible in
   lightning.
4. If it is unmanaged package,you can click on edit and Set 'Show in
   Lightning Experience' to true.

One more thing you need to check is if the Application is accessible to your profile or not.You will find the same when you edit the App.

Let me know if it helps.